# MVVM ObservableCollection items to string

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using PRISM6.
In my Model I have simple:

```
public ObservableCollection<Id> Ids { get; }
```

In ViewModel I would like to return those items in `public ObservableCollection<string> Ids`

How can I convert it to string? At this moment I have:

```
private ObservableCollection<string> _ids = new ObservableCollection<string>();
public ObservableCollection<string> Ids {
        get {
            _ids.Add("Empty");
            foreach (var item in _Model.Ids) {
                _ids.Add(item.ToString());
            }
            return _ids;
        }
}
```

But it does not work when I update my collection in Model.

My old version without convert works fine. `public ObservableCollection<Id> Ids => _Model.Ids;` I need it in string because somehow I need to add "Empty" to combobox. If ther is any better solution for it please tell me :)

Comment: Try initializing your `ObservableCollection` in the getter: `get { _ids = new ObservableCollection<string>();...`

Comment: @Pikoh It is not working ;/

Comment: Most likely you forgot the ProperyChange when the id were set

Comment: So, now in your model you have `public ObservableCollection<Id> Ids { get; }` instead of `public ObservableCollection<Id> Ids => _Model.Ids;`? Why did you change that?

Comment: @Pikoh `public ObservableCollection<Id> Ids { get; }` is in my Model
`ObservableCollection<Id> Ids => _Model.Ids` is from ViewModel, its my peperty which is binded to combobox

I would like to Bind this property:`ObservableCollection<string> _ids`

Comment: Personally, I would just reuse the collection in my view. If it needs to show something different (not available in the binding), I could always use a `IValueConverter`. But if you really want to keep 2 collections in-sync, you can try using `CollectionChangedEventManager`. Simply handle the event when the source collection have changed, and rebuild your new collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there are much better solutions out there, but here's one method I particularly like:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    // Source Id collection
    public ObservableCollection<Id> Ids { get; }

    // Empty Id collection
    public ObservableCollection<Id> Empty { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Id>();

    // Composite (combination of Source + Empty collection)
    // View should bind to this instead of Ids
    public CompositeCollection ViewIds { get; }

    // Constructor
    public MainViewModel(ObservableCollection<Id> ids)
    {
        ViewIds = new CompositeCollection();
        ViewIds.Add(new CollectionContainer {Collection = Empty });
        ViewIds.Add(new CollectionContainer {Collection = Ids = ids });

        // Whenever something changes in Ids, Update the collections
        CollectionChangedEventManager.AddHandler(Ids, delegate { UpdateEmptyCollection(); });

        UpdateEmptyCollection(); // First time
    }

    private void UpdateEmptyCollection()
    {
        // If the source collection is empty, push an "Empty" id into the Empty colleciton
        if (Ids.Count == 0)
            Empty.Add(new Id("Empty"));

        // Otherwise (has Ids), clear the Empty collection
        else
            Empty.Clear();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is amazing! Thanks a lot :)